# Changing class of all li elements javascript/jquery button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a site with an accordion style script i've found. I'm quite new to jquery/javascript, so please bear with me...

My basic page opens an accordion, where the first one is locked open, and the other ones opens/closes if pressed. What keeps my top panel locked open is a

```
<li class="locked">.
```

The other panels have only

```
 <li>
```

no class. I guess I can call them

```
 <li class="somethingelse">
```

I want a button in my top panel that changes all the

to

```
   <li class="locked">, so that the user can view the entire site.
```

I have tried:

```
 <div>
 <ul>
  <li class="locked">Something
 <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
 </li>
 <li id="abcd" class="somethingelse">somethingelse</li>
 <li id="abcd"class="somethingelse">somethingelse</li>
 </ul>
 </div> 

 <script>
 function myFunction() {
 document.getElementById("abcd").class = "locked";
 }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be changing element class as below

```
document.getElementById("abcd").className = "locked";
```

If you want to select more then one element use class name:

```
var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName("somethingelse");
```

So your final function will look like:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName("somethingelse");
  var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(nodes);
  arr.forEach( function(node) {
      node.className = "locked";
  });
}
```

```css
li {
  color: #000000;
}
li.locked {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="locked">Something
      <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
    </li>
    <li id="abcd" class="somethingelse">somethingelse</li>
    <li id="abcd" class="somethingelse">somethingelse</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In plain JavaScript, I'd suggest:

```
function myFunction() {
    // retrieves a NodeList of all <li> elements that do not
    // have the 'locked' class-name:
    var liElements = document.querySelectorAll('li:not(.locked)');

    // uses Array.prototype.forEach to iterate over the array-like
    // NodeList:
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(liElements, function (li, index, list) {
        // first argument ('li' ): the current array-element,
        // second argument ('index'): unused, the index of the current
        // array-element in the array,
        // third argument ('list'): the array itself

        // adding the 'locked' class-name to the list of classes
        // of the current node:
        li.classList.add('locked');
    });
}
```

```css
li {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

li.locked {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="locked">Something
      <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
    </li>
    <li class="somethingelse">somethingelse</li>
    <li class="somethingelse">somethingelse</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var liElements = document.querySelectorAll('li:not(.locked)');

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(liElements, function (li, index, list) {
    li.classList.add('locked');
  });
}
</script>
```

Further, I'd suggest binding the event-handling in JavaScript, rather than using in-line HTML attributes (`onclick`, etc), which makes for easier long-term maintenance (since everything's updated in the same place, and you don't have to remember where all the event-handling was assigned):

```js
function myFunction() {
  var liElements = document.querySelectorAll('li:not(.locked)');

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(liElements, function(li, index, list) {
    li.classList.add('locked');
  });
}

// finding the first element that matches the CSS selector.
// adding the named function (myFunction) as a 'click'
// event-handler:
document.querySelector('li.locked button').addEventListener('click', myFunction);
```

```css
li {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
li.locked {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="locked">Something
      <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
    </li>
    <li class="somethingelse">somethingelse</li>
    <li class="somethingelse">somethingelse</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

References:

- CSS:

  - [Negation (`:not()`) pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#negation).
- JavaScript:

  - [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelector).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).
  - [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).